# Change button text on mouseover by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the button text is "followed" and the user hovers over it I want the text to change to "unfollow" and change back to "followed" once the user stops hovering.

Button:

```
{%if follow%}
<button type="submit" id="status" class="button" value="True"><span>followed</span></button>

{%else%}
<button type="submit" id="status" class="button" value="False"><span>follow</span></button>

{%endif%}
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function() {
        var status = $("#status").val();
        var course = $("#course").html()

        //SECTION THAT I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH
        if ($(".button span").html() == "followed") {
            $(".button").mouseover(function() {
            $(".button span").html() = "unfollow";
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/follow",
            data: 'status=' + status + "&course=" + course,
            success: function() {
$(".button span").html($(".button span").html() == 'followed' ? 'follow' : 'followed');
$(".button").val($(".button").val() == 'True' ? 'False' : 'True');
}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When I run this I get

```
405 Method Not Allowed

The method POST is not allowed for this resource.
```

But when I remove the mouseover code it works. What's wrong with the mouseover code?

Edit:
Updated jQuery that now works, outside of onclick code, with mouseout:

```
if ($(".button span").html() == "followed") {
$(".button").mouseover(function() {
    $(".button span").html("unfollow");
});
$(".button").mouseout(function() {
    $(".button span").html("followed");
});
}
```

Edit:
Actually, with the code above, if the button is "followed" and I click it, the button text remains "followed". I think this is because the mouseout function is overriding the ajax success function that changes it to "follow". How do I override the "followed" mouseout function once I click the button?

Comment: `$(".button span").html("unfollow");` Don't assign to `html()`, pass it a string. Not sure if that's your only issue though - the 405 error seems unrelated. Perhaps it only responds to GET?

Comment: I think the remote resouce is not allowing post request

Comment: The remote resource problem is because you are getting response from a **FOLDER**, not a PHP file...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try the following, you were missing the ");" on your mouseover call, which was borking everything after that...

```
//SECTION THAT I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH
if ($(".button span").html() == "followed") {

    $(".button").mouseover(function() {
        // Pass the new string into .html()
        $(".button span").html("unfollow");
    });
}
```

Comment: probably not, lol, but i'm addressing why it works when he removes the code and breaks when he puts it in.  More to the point, i'm answering his question:  "What's wrong with the mouseover code?"

Comment: nice catch Michael, didn't see that one.  OP: i think you have multiple issues, as Louis, Michael and myself have pointed out.  Best to go through this more carefully now that we have fixed a handful of said issues.

Comment: Thanks guys. I updated the code. Also, side question - what's the purpose of the "return false;" line in the click event code?

Comment: When you return false from an event handler it prevents the default action for that event and stops the event bubbling up through the DOM. That is, much like event.preventDefault and event.stopPropogation would do.... also event.cancelBubble i believe...

Comment: Oh wait, the current code doesn't actually work completely as intended; is there a way to override the mouseout function? Or is the bug something else? (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#status').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('span').text('unfollow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('span').text('followed');
    });
});
```

Hope this can help.
http://jsfiddle.net/sing0920/54yfg/

Answer (score 1):

You should try to restrict your JavaScript usage to when it's necessary. You can achieve the same through regular CSS. Here's an example:

```
.button:hover .initialText, .hoverText {
    display: none;
}
.button:hover .hoverText {
    display: block;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="button">
    <span class="initialText">Followed</span>
    <span class="hoverText">Unfollow</span>
</div>
```